# Jmeter Selinium webdriver - UI load testing, result analysis

Tags: jmeter

I am doing UI load testing using distributed Jmeter Selinium webdriver
I have successfully execute the script and obtain the result.
Even though i have obtained the result with success status of 200 code, But how to confirm that all threads has successfully loaded the web pages including images and thumbnails
is there any assertion to very this or any suggestion pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unless there is a error in your script you will always get 200 as the status code. You could use [WDS.sampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) shorthand to set whether it is successful or not conditionally basing on your acceptance criteria

   If you need to verify presence of a certain element or it's being displayed you could use [WDS.browser.findElement()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) function and check whether it is [displayed](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed())
2. You can also [take a screenshot](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) and compare it to the reference one using i.e. [OpenCV Java bindings](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) with [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the language
3. WebDriver sampler returns the page source code as the response so you can also use [Size Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Size_Assertion) to check if the response size is equal or larger than the anticipated one or [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to check if certain text is present or not
4. And last but not the lease using real browsers for performance testing is not recommended either by [Selenium project](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/) or by [WebDriver sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) developers

   > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

   So I would rather recommend reconsidering your approach and create the main load using JMeter's [HTTP Request samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) and use WebDriver Sampler for checking client side metrics like rendering time or JavaScript execution time.